# Asp.Net and namespaces splitted over multiple .cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net

in the site i'm building, i've got 2 .cs files under a subdirectory in the wwwroot. Said files contain a bunch of utility functions and belong to the same namespace (ie: namespace myUtils)

being the content of those 2 files in the same namespace, i expected to be able to use some classes from one in the other and vice versa, as if all the code was in one big file, but apparently it doesn't work

example code:

file 1:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections;

namespace myincludes
{
    public static class myConfig
    {
    public static String dbaddress = "127.0.0.1";
    }
}
```

file 2:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections;

namespace myincludes
{
    public static class myUtil
    {
        public static void doStuff()
        {
            String test = myConfig.dbaddress;
        }
    }
}
```

aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Assembly src="./includes/file1.cs" %>
<%@ Assembly src="./includes/file2.cs" %>

<%%>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>hi</body>
</html>
```

i get a compilation error saying

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'myConfig' does not exist in the current context
```

there is basically no documentation of such usage of the Assembly src directive. What seems to be the common route is to produce a binary DLL but i'd rather not...

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but you should read [C# Coding Conventions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx). Your code doesn't seem to follow the typical C# convention, which is often expected if you're going to be sharing your code with others. It also makes your code easier to read by breaking up the different words (such as MyIncludes instead of myincludes).

Comment: did you ever figure out an answer? I too would like to have multiple *.cs files compiled by IIS at runtime.

Comment: you have to put everything in one file. yes, it sucks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class myUtil
{
    public static string test { get{return myConfig.dbaddress;}}

    public static string SomeMethod()
    {
       return myConfig.dbaddress;
    }

}
```

You have to call the code from a valid location. Right now your call is outside any method or property. It's not in a valid location. Look at my examples above where I wrap it in a property and a method.

Comment: yea sorry i forgot to put a method there when i cut down the code to make it as clear as possible. it doesn't work however, i think it's more compiler related than code, so either there must be some funky way to tell the compiler the right message or something else

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should work just as you intended, without any problem. I assume from your Assembly directives that you'd like to use `myConfig` in your ASPX markup? To do that, rather than the Assembly directives, simply import your namespace:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="myincludes" %>
```

Then you can use `myConfig` in your markup:

```
  dbaddress is: <%=myConfig.dbaddress %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be using a Web Site project, rather than a Web Application that is pre-compiled. If you just dump a .cs file in a random directory, ASP.NET will not find it unless you explicitly refer to it*.

Try placing the files in a special directory `App_Code` right below the web root. Source files placed there will be compiled automatically. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t990ks23%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for some additional explanation.

*: for example, ASP.NET Web Forms pages generally start with `@Page` directive with
 `CodeFile` attribute pointing to the source file.